# Logging Lambda functions in TypeScript with HOF

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to log my incoming APIGatewayEvent events from aws-lambda with an HOF. My Idea looks as follows:

1. Describe Higher Order Function to log/stdout all events
2. Wrap my AWS functions in export with the HOF

Pattern should look like this: export const myLambdaFunction = withLogger(myLambdaFunction);

My lambda function looks as followed:

```
const getProfileHandler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  // Parse request parameters
  const { requestContext } = event;
  //do something with event
  const response = otherFunction(event)
  return response
```

And my logger function looks like this:

```
export function logWrapper<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  func: T,
): (...funcArgs: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> {
  const funcName = func.name;
  console.log(funcName);
  // Return a new function that logs the parameters of the original function
  return (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    //console.log(event);
    const results = func(...args);
    return results;
  };
}
```

How can i stdout the event that is inside the Lambda Function? Or is it even possible with the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution for now is as follows. It consists out of a wrapper function (for the handler functions) a contextStore singleton which can read/write a trace-id and a logger function.

```
type HofLogger = (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback<APIGatewayProxyResult>,
) => void | Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>;

export function withLogger(func: APIGatewayProxyHandler): HofLogger {
  const funcName = func.name;
  return (...args): void | Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    store.setRequestIdentifier(args[0]);
    const message = funcName + ' called';
    logger.info(message, args);
    const results = func(...args);
    return results;
  };
}
```

It can wrap any export of a handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close.

The HOF accepts an `APIGatewayProxyHandler` and returns an `APIGatewayProxyHandler`.

```
export function logWrapper<T extends APIGatewayProxyHandler>(
  func: T,
): APIGatewayProxyHandler {
  const funcName = func.name;
  console.log(funcName);
  // Return a new function that logs the parameters of the original function
  return (event, context): ReturnType<T> => {
    console.log(event);
    const results = func(event, context);
    return results;
  };
}
```